# Debug a Python C/C++ Pybind11 extension in VSCode [Linux]

Tags: python, c++, debugging, visual-studio-code, pybind11

## Problem Statement

I want to run and debug my own C++ extensions for python in "hybrid mode" in VSCode. Since defining your own python wrappers can be quite tedious, I want to use [`pybind11`](https://github.com/pybind/pybind11) to link C++ and python. I love the debugging tools of vscode, so I would like to debug both my python scripts as well as the C++ functions in vscode.

Fortunately, debugging python and C++ files simultaneously is possible by first starting the python debugger and then attach a gdb debugger to that process as described in detail in [nadiah's blog post](https://nadiah.org/2020/03/01/example-debug-mixed-python-c-in-visual-studio-code/) (Windows users, please note [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66077410/debug-a-python-c-c-extension-in-vscode-on-windows)). This works fine for me. Unfortunately, they define the C++ -- python bindings manually. I would like to use `pybind11` instead.

I created a simplified example that is aligned with nadiah's example using `pybind11`. Debugging the python file works but the gdb debugger doesn't stop in the `.cpp` file. According to [this github question](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2900) it should be theoretically possible but there are no details on how to achieve this.

## Steps to reproduce

Here I try to follow nadiahs example as closely as possible but include `pybind11` wrappers.

### Setting up the package

Create a virtual environment (also works with anaconda, as described below)

```
virtualenv --python=python3.8 myadd
cd myadd/
. bin/activate
```

Create file `myadd.cpp`

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

float method_myadd(float arg1, float arg2) {
    float return_val = arg1 + arg2;
    return return_val;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(myadd, handle) {
    handle.doc() = "This is documentation";
    handle.def("myadd", &method_myadd);
}
```

, `myscript.py`

```
import myadd

print("going to ADD SOME NUMBERS")

x = myadd.myadd(5,6)

print(x)
```

and `setup.py`

```
from glob import glob
from distutils.core import setup, Extension
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension

def main():
    setup(name="myadd",
          version="1.0.0",
          description="Python interface for the myadd C library function",
          author="Nadiah",
          author_email="nadiah@nadiah.org",
          ext_modules=[Pybind11Extension("myadd",["myadd.cpp"])],
          )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Clone the pybind11 repo

```
git clone git@github.com:pybind/pybind11.git
```

and install the python package

```
pip install pybind11
```

Run the setup script

```
python3 setup.py install
```

Now, we can already run the python script

```
python myscript.py
```

### Setting up vscode

Open `vscode`

```
code .
```

Select the python interpreter with `Ctrl`+`Shift`+`p` -> `Select python interpreter` -> `./bin/python`, now in the lower bar, you should see virtualenv `myadd`.
Create the `launch.json` file by clicking the debug symbol and 'Create new launch configuration'.
This is my `launch.json` (This might be the problem)

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "myscript.py",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        },
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Attach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/bin/python", /* My virtual env */
            "processId": "${command:pickProcess}",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ],
            "additionalSOLibSearchPath": "${workspaceFolder}/build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8;${workspaceFolder}/lib;${workspaceFolder}/lib/python3.8/site-packages/myadd-1.0.0-py3.8-linux-x86_64.egg/"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note that I added the `"additionalSOLibSearchPath"` option in accordance to the [github question](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2900) but it did not change anything.

### Debugging

In vscode, add breakpoints in `myscript.py` in line 5 and 7, and in `myadd.cpp` in line 5.
Now, first start the python debugger and let it stop on the breakpoint in line 5.
Then go to a terminal and get the correct process id of the running python script.

```
ps aux | grep python
```

The second to last process is the correct one in my case. E.g.

```
username      **65715**  3.0  0.0 485496 29812 pts/3    Sl+  10:37   0:00 /home/username/myadd/bin/python /home/username/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2022.0.1814523869/pythonFiles/lib/python/debugpy --connect 127.0.0.1:38473 --configure-qt none --adapter-access-token ... myscript.py
```

In this example, `65715` would be the correct process id.
Now, in vscode start the (gdb) Attach debugger and type in the process id in the search bar. Hit enter, now you need to type `y` in the console to allow the attaching and type in your sudo password.
If you are following nadiah's example, you can now press continue on the python debug bar and the script will stop on the C++ breakpoint.
For this pybind11 example, the script does not stop on the C++ breakpoint.

### Project Structure

Your project structure now should look like this

```
myadd
| bin/
| build/
| dist/
| lib/
| myadd.cpp
| myadd.egg-info/
| myscript.py
| pybind11/
| setup.py
```

## Things I also tried

As stated in the [github post](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/2900), one has to ensure that the debug flag is set. Therefore, I added a `setup.cfg` file

```
[build_ext]
debug=1
[aliases]
debug_install = build_ext --debug install
```

And ran

```
python setup.py debug_install
```

but this did not help as well.

## Using anaconda instead of virtualenv

Using conda instead of virtualenv is quite easy. Just create your env as usual and then type in

```
which python
```

to get the path to the python executable. Replace the `"program"` in the `(gdb) Attach` debug configuration of your `launch.json` with this path.

## Software versions

I run

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Vscode 1.64.2 x64
- GNU gdb 9.2
- gcc 9.3.0
- python 3.8 as defined in the virtualenv.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## TLDR

I think the C++ code was not build with debug information.
Adding the keyword argument `extra_compile_args=["-g"]` to the `Pybind11Extension` in the `setup.py` may be enough to solve it.

Regardless read on for my solution proposal, that worked for me.

## Steps

I could make this work by using the [Python C++ Debugger extension by BeniBenj](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjamin-simmonds.pythoncpp-debug), by setting the C++ flag `-g` and by using the `--no-clean` pip flag. For the sake of completeness, I am going to enclose here my minimal working project.

Create the bindings in the `add.cpp` file:

```
#include <pybind11/pybind11.h>

float cpp_add(float arg1, float arg2) {
    float return_val = arg1 + arg2;
    return return_val;
}

PYBIND11_MODULE(my_add, handle) {
    handle.doc() = "This is documentation";
    handle.def("cpp_add", &cpp_add);
}
```

Create the testing python script:

```
import my_add


if __name__ == "__main__":

    x = 5
    y = 6
    print(f"Adding {x} and {y} together.")
    z = my_add.cpp_add(x, y)
    print(f"Result is {z}")
```

Create the `setup.py` file:

```
import os
from distutils.core import setup
from pybind11.setup_helpers import Pybind11Extension


setup(name="myadd",
      version="1.0.0",
      ext_modules=[Pybind11Extension("my_add", ["add.cpp"], extra_compile_args=["-g"])],
      )
```

The important thing about the `setup.py` file is that it builds the C++ code with debug information. I have the suspicion that this is what was missing for you.

The package can be installed with:

```
pip install --no-clean ./
```

The `--no-clean` is important. It prevents the sources that your debugger will try to open from being deleted.

Now is the time for launching both the Python and the C++ debuggers. I am using the [Python C++ Debugger extension by BeniBenj](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjamin-simmonds.pythoncpp-debug) as [recommended by the creator](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/8865#issuecomment-1152380471) in a Github issue. After installing it, just create a debug config by clicking on the "create a launch.json file", selecting "Python C++ Debugger" and than choosing from the options. (For me both the `Default` and the `Custom: GDB` worked.)

Place the breakpoints in both the python and the C++ code. (In the python code, I recommend placing them on the line with the binded code and the one after it.) Select your script and run the "Python C++ Debugger" configuration. The code should pause on entry, and on the second terminal that just opened this question should appear:

```
Superuser access is required to attach to a process. Attaching as superuser can potentially harm your computer. Do you want to continue? [y/N]
```

Answer `y`. Start debugging. Upon reaching your binded code in python, you may have to click manually in the call stack (in the debug panel on the left) to actually switch into the C++ code.

## Extra info

### Building the C++ code with debug information.

I could not find online how to set the compiler flags within the `setup.py`.
Therefore I looked into the source code of the `Pybind11Extension`. There I saw this line:

```
env_cppflags = os.environ.get("CPPFLAGS", "")
```

This suggested that I can set the flags with environment variables, and indeed I could. I added this line in the `setup.py` before the `setup()` function:

```
os.environ["CPPFLAGS"] = "-g"
```

However, as I was typing this answer I also saw this comment in the pybind11 source code:

```
# flags are prepended, so that they can be further overridden, e.g. by
# ``extra_compile_args=["-g"]``.
```

I tested it and it works too. However, I could not find it in the documentation. That is the main reason I am including these steps here.

### Keeping the sources

For me. when the debugger pauses on the breakpoint within the C++ code, it wants to open the source file within `tmp/pip-req-build-o1w6len6/add.cpp`. If the `--no-clean` option is not kept in the pip installation, then this file will not be found. (I had to create it and copy the source code into it.)

### launch.json

Here is the Custom: GDB configuration, where the "miDebuggerPath" parameter may be deleted:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python C++ Debugger",
            "type": "pythoncpp",
            "request": "launch",
            "pythonLaunchName": "Python: Current File",
            "cppAttachName": "(gdb) Attach"
        },
        {
            "name": "(gdb) Attach",
            "type": "cppdbg",
            "request": "attach",
            "program": "/home/dudly01/anaconda3/envs/trash_env/bin/python",
            "processId": "",
            "MIMode": "gdb",
            "miDebuggerPath": "/path/to/gdb or remove this attribute for the path to be found automatically",
            "setupCommands": [
                {
                    "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                    "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                    "ignoreFailures": true
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "Python: Current File",
            "type": "python",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "console": "integratedTerminal"
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the default configuration:

```
{
    // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
    // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
    // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Python C++ Debugger",
            "type": "pythoncpp",
            "request": "launch",
            "pythonConfig": "default",
            "cppConfig": "default (gdb) Attach"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: This solved the issue. Most likely, it was the g flag. I'm not able to use the Python C++ Debugger extension by BeniBenj package because it does not ask me for permission. However, the manual method with `ps aux | grep python` that I described above works for me. Thank you!

Comment: @JakobThumm thanks for checking it. I am glad that you made it work.
How did you start debugging? With the "Debug Python File" button on the top-right side? Or with the button on the left side, that is within the Run and Debug tab, that is on the side panel? The extension works with the latter. The shortcut for me is F5 (after selecting the Python C++ Debugger config).

Comment: I'm starting it through the Run and Debug side bar.

Comment: This post is extremely helpful!  It even works on WSL2 windows with ubuntu WSL. You need to install [Python C++ Debugger](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjamin-simmonds.pythoncpp-debug) remotely on WSL2 ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I also meet this problem in debugging Python and C++ using pybind11.

Same steps as the most credit answer, except that my VSCode terminal can't type the user password when debugging by GDB attach. The output message is like below:

```
Authenticating as: admin,,, (admin1) Password: [1] + Stopped (tty output) /usr/bin/pkexec "/usr/bin/gdb" --interpreter=mi --tty=${DbgTerm} 0<"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-In-cdlwi1ey.d0f" 1>"/tmp/Microsoft-MIEngine-Out-yeoazv5q.ght" You have stopped jobs
```

To solve this, set ptrace_scope to 0 so that we allow one process to examine and modify another process.

```
echo 0 | sudo tee /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope
```

After that, I can set breakpoint in both Python and C++ and get the call stack of pybind11.